# TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'count' when using lambda to sort a python 3 dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.6

I was trying to figure out how lambda function works. With python 3 I tried to sort a dictionary from largest to smallest based on the value.

`word_counts={"Wong":28, "Joe":20, "Tim":12, "Kate":6}`
`wc=sorted(word_counts.items(), key=lambda (word, count):count, reverse=True)`

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Since the first lambda parenthesis was highlighted, so I removed parentheses from the lambda function and received a different error message as below

`wc=sorted(word_counts.items(), key=lambda word, count : count, reverse=True)`

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#77>", line 1, in <module>
    wc=sorted(word_counts.items(), key=lambda word, count : count, reverse=True)
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'count'`

Anyone has an idea what I did wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first code actually works in Python 2, but in Python 3 the capability to unpack tuple parameters of a function was removed per [PEP-3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/), so you can no longer specify the parameters as a tuple to be unpacked as `word` and `count` as you do in `lambda (word, count):count`. Instead, you just have to use an index to specify the second item in the given tuple:

```
wc = sorted(word_counts.items(), key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)
```